# Hello everyone, is there any way to change navbar color when scrolled on certain page?

Tags: html, css, colors, responsive-design, navbar

First 3 pages are black and my navbar is set to transparent and color of nav items are white but when I scroll on my 4th page(which is kinda colorful) my nav items become not much visible ...so the question is: Is there any way I can change my navbar color while on that certain page using **ONLY HTML and CSS?**

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add minimal reproducible code.

Comment: You should add classes or attribute individually and apply CSS accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you share piece of code and the causing issue. Still, here is and example for navbar color change on scroll.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 300) {
        $(".black").css("background" , "blue");
      }

      else{
          $(".black").css("background" , "#333");   
      }
  })
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:1000px;
}
.black{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:#333;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  
}
.black ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}

.black ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  color:red;
}

.blue{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="black">
  <ul>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OP does not want to use JS